# Problem connecting to SQL server via FreeTDS/UnixOdbc

Tags: python, odbc

I am trying to connect to MS-SQL server via ODBC, 
probably this is one of most asked questions but this one is very strange because same configuration works in my local machine, I mean I did everything on my local computer and its OK, but now in other machine not working.

I've installed prerequisite packages via

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev freetds-bin tdsodbc
```

My configurations

```
/etc/freetds/freetds.conf
# A typical Microsoft server
[SQLDemo]
host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0      # I've tried 7.0, 7.2 as well
-----------------------------------------------
/etc/odbc.ini
[SQLDemo]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace = No
Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQL2014      #I've tried servername=SQLDemo as well
Database = MY_DB_NAME
-----------------------------------------------
/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC]
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/home/odbc_trace.log

[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS Driver (Sysbase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup =  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

I'm running below piece of code and get the error

```
cnnstr = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % ('SQLDemo', 'xyz', 'xyz');
db = pyodbc.connect(cnnstr);

pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I need to know whats wrong here.
I need to mention again same config/code works in my local computer.

both machines are **Ubuntu 16.04**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to the default port of SQL Server instance in target machine, it was changed to 1434. so all the configuration is correct juts need to adjust the port number, also before connecting make sure about the SQL Server's port.